# Android Studio detect when rotated

Tags: android, android-studio, rotation, detect

I want to have my application be able to do certain things when the application rotates or changes from portrait to landscape.

I thought of using a shake event listener, but I want the device to only run its function when it has been tilted a certain amount. I figure the best way to do this is to have the device listen when it is switched from portrait to landscape.

I was wondering if there was a method such as: `onRotate()` or `onEnterLandscape()` so I can have my actions only executed when the device is rotated, something like this:

```
onEnterLandscape() {
    device.launchGoodies;
}

onEnterPortrait() {
    device.stopGoodies;
}
```

Or even,

```
onDeviceRotate(90 degrees) {
    device.launchGoodies;
}

onDeviceReturnToStart() {
    devoce.stopGoodies;
}
```

I was wondering if there were any methods like this, or any others which would work better.

Thanks!

Nathan

Answer (score 0):

You could try using OrientationEventListener and calling your functions from  onOrientationChanged().

Or you could use a flag to remember previous orientation and check it in onCreate() for change (since activity is recreated on orientation change).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html